# swift : shortcut for guard "let self = ..."?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I have to parse json server response into a swift object. I use this code :

```
struct MyGPSCoords {

    var latitude:Double
    var longitude:Double
    var accuracy:Int
    var datetime:NSDate

    init?(infobrutFromJson_:[String:String]?)
    {
        guard let infobrut = infobrutFromJson_ else {
            // first time the user sign up to the app, php server returns "null" in Json 
            return nil
        }

        guard
        let lat:Double = Double(infobrut["latitude"] ?? "nil"),
        let lng = Double(infobrut["longitude"] ?? "nil"),
        let acc = Int(infobrut["accuracy"] ?? "nil"),
        let dtm = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(infobrut["time"] ?? "nil"))
        else {
            print("warning : unable to parse data from server. Returning nil");
            return nil ; // position not NIL but format not expected => = nil
        }
        self.latitude = lat
        self.longitude = lng
        self.accuracy = acc
        self.datetime = dtm
    }


}
```

I want to make the "guard" statement as short as possible. First, I added `?? "nil"` so if one of the keys doesn't exist, `Double("nil")` gets `nil` and guard statement can handle. For NSDate, I made an extension with a convenience `init?` returning nil if its input is nil, so I can do the same.

My question is, can i do it even shorter by assigning directly to self.latitude the values right in the `guard` statement ? I tried that :

```
guard self.latitude = Double(infobrut["latitude"] ?? "nil"), ...
```

It says it cannot cast from `Double?` to `Double`. Is there any way to make this guard even shorter and avoiding me to assign lat, lng, acc and dtm buffering variables ?

Comment: @Damon yes you can? `var a: String = "1";
var b = Int(a);

print(a, type(of: b));` --> `// 1 Optional<Int>`

Comment: Your properties should be `let`, not `var`

Comment: You could use `Codable`?

Comment: Decode `MyGPSCoords` directly from JSON using `Decodable`. Don't get `infobrutFromJson_` through `NSJSONSerializer` first

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know Decodable protocol and it seems its exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Codable is great but if you JSON is using strings for number values, you'll have to declare them as strings in your model as well. If you have control over the API I would suggest fixing that first.

Comment: Decodable won’t help if the JSON really is `[String: String]`. What does the actual JSON look like, and how is it converted to the `infobrutFromJson_` dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that question is old but I have to admit that I didn't understand very well the in-built Decodable/Decoder system in Swift (especially this notion of "Container", can't figure out what it represents exactly)

Anyway, I made my own decoder which enable to handle this situation in quite the same way as Android does (to decode JSONObject). I made an extension of Dictionary like this :

```
protocol Decodable {
    init(from raw:[String:Any]) throws
}


extension Dictionary where Key == String
{

    enum DecodableError : Error {
        case unknownKey(key:String)
        case keyWrongType(key:String, expectedType:String, actualValue:String)
        case nullValueAtKey(key:String)
    }
    
    func getSafe<T>(_ key:String, forType t:T.Type) throws -> T
    {
        if(self[key] != nil)
        {
            if(self[key] is NSNull) // corresponds to the JSON null value (by experience)
            {
                throw DecodableError.nullValueAtKey(key:key)
            }
            else if(self[key] is T) // for raw type
            {
                return self[key] as! T
            }
            
            // try to parse self[key] to provided type if it's decodable
            else if(self[key] is [String:Any] && t is Decodable.Type)
            {
                return try (t as! Decodable.Type).init(from: self[key] as! [String:Any]) as! T
            }
            
            throw DecodableError.keyWrongType(key: key,
                    expectedType: String(describing: T.self),
                    actualValue: String(describing:self[key]!))
            
        }
            
        throw DecodableError.unknownKey(key:key)
        
    }
    
    func getSafeOpt<T>(_ key:String, forType t:T.Type) throws -> T?
    {
        if(self[key] != nil)
        {
            if(self[key] is NSNull)
            {
                return nil
            }
            return try getSafe(key, forType: t)
        
        }
            
        throw DecodableError.unknownKey(key:key)
    }
    
}
```

I use it like that :

```
struct Position : Decodable {
    
    
    let latitude:Double
    let longitude:Double
    let accuracy:Int?
    let member:Member

    init(from raw:[String:Any]) throws
    {
    
        // getSafe throw exception whenever node are json<null> or if node doesn't exist 
        latitude = try raw.getSafe("lat", forType: Double.self)
        longitude = try raw.getSafe("lng", forType: Double.self)

        // getSafeOpt returns nil if the JSON value of node acc is null, 
        // but it still throw an exception if there is no "acc" node 
        accuracy = try raw.getSafeOpt("acc", forType: Int.self)

        // you can use it to decode other objects that implement my Decodable protocol too : 
        member = try raw.getSafeOpt("member", forType: Member.self)
    }
 } 
 
do {
   try app.position = Position(from: rawDic)
}
catch {
    print("Unable to parse Position : \(error) ")
    return
}
```

This does not handle yet the JSON arrays, I'll do it later, or feel free to update my answer if you wish to add a JSON array handling mechanism.

Answer (score 5):

First, you should of course try to fix the JSON, since this JSON is malformed. Strings are not numbers in JSON. Assuming you cannot correct this broken JSON, the tool you want is `flatMap`, which converts T?? to T? (which is what guard-let expects).

```
guard
    let lat = infobrut["latitude"].flatMap(Double.init),
    let lng = infobrut["longitude"].flatMap(Double.init),
    let acc = infobrut["accuracy"].flatMap(Int.init),
    let dtm = infobrut["time"].flatMap(TimeInterval.init).flatMap(Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970:))
    else {
        print("warning : unable to parse data from server. Returning nil")
        return nil // position not NIL but format not expected => = nil
}
```

---

I saw a lot of comments that Codable won't work here, but it absolutely will, and it's really what you should use. Here's one way (this is a little sloppy about its error messages, but it's simple):

```
struct MyGPSCoords: Decodable {

    var latitude:Double
    var longitude:Double
    var accuracy:Int
    var datetime:Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude, longitude, accuracy, datetime
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        guard
            let lat = Double(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .latitude)),
            let lng = Double(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .longitude)),
            let acc = Int(try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .accuracy)),
            let dtm = TimeInterval(try container.decode(String.self,
                                                        forKey: .datetime)).flatMap(Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970:))
        else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Could not decode"))
        }

        self.latitude = lat
        self.longitude = lng
        self.accuracy = acc
        self.datetime = dtm
    }

}
```

---

Or you can get really fancy with an internal helpful function and get rid of all the temporary variables and optionals through the power of `throws`.

```
struct MyGPSCoords: Decodable {

    var latitude:Double
    var longitude:Double
    var accuracy:Int
    var datetime:Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude, longitude, accuracy, datetime
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        func decodeBrokenJSON<T>(_ type: T.Type,
                                 forKey key: CodingKeys) throws -> T
            where T: Decodable & LosslessStringConvertible {
                return try T.init(container.decode(String.self, forKey: key)) ?? {
                    throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: key,
                                                           in: container,
                                                           debugDescription: "Could not decode \(key)")
                    }()
        }

        self.latitude = try decodeBrokenJSON(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
        self.longitude = try decodeBrokenJSON(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
        self.accuracy = try decodeBrokenJSON(Int.self, forKey: .accuracy)
        self.datetime = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: try decodeBrokenJSON(TimeInterval.self, forKey: .datetime))
    }

}
```

(IMO, this is a great example of how `throws` really shines and should be used much more than it commonly is.)

Comment: Can drop the ; after `return nil` and your print

Comment: You don't need the explicit `CodingKeys` enum, since the keys are identical to the property names.

Comment: @NRitH I don't think that's true. What do you pass as `keyedBy:`? Can you give it a try?

Comment: I mean you don't need it if your struct implements `Codable`. In my answer, I outline how this would work.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is not possible. The compiler already tells you so, even though the error message is a bit misleading. You can either use a `guard let` that creates a new variable, or you can use a `guard` with a boolean expression.  In your case there is no `let` so the compiler tries to parse a boolean expression. Instead it sees the assignment and produces the error message that the types don’t match. If the types would match (as in `guard self.latitude = 12.0`) the error message would be clearer: `error: use of '=' in a boolean context, did you mean '=='?`

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions seem overly complicated. Simply make it

```
struct MyGPSCoords: Codable {

    var latitude: Double?
    var longitude: Double?
    var accuracy: Int?
    var datetime: Date?

    var isValid {
        return [latitude, longitude, accuracy, datetime].filter { $0 == nil }.isEmpty
    }
}

// jsonData is whatever payload you get back from the URL request.
let coords = JSONDecoder().decode(jsonData, type: MyGPSCoords.self)

if !coords.isValid {
    print("warning : unable to parse data from server.")
}
```

Since all of your properties are `Optional`, parsing can't fail if one or more of them is missing. The `isValid` check is much simpler than the `guard let...` clause in your original code.

**EDIT:** If, as Rob Napier suggests, all the JSON values are encoded as `String`s, then here's another way to structure your `MyGPSCoords`:

```
struct MyGPSCoords: Codable {

    // These are the Codable properties
    fileprivate var latitudeString: String?
    fileprivate var longitudeString: String?
    fileprivate var accuracyString: String?
    fileprivate var datetimeString: String?

    // Default constant to use as a default check for validity
    let invalid = Double.leastNonzeroMagnitude

    // And these are the derived properties that you want users to use
    var latitude: Double {
        return Double(latitudeString ?? "\(invalid)") ?? invalid
    }

    var longitude: Double {
        return Double(longitudeString ?? "\(invalid)") ?? invalid
    }

    var accuracy: Int {
        return Int(accuracyString ?? "\(invalid)") ?? Int(invalid)
    }

    var date: Date {
        return <whatever-formatter-output-you-need>
    }

    var isValid {
        return [latitudeString, longitudeString, accuracyString, datetimeString].filter { $0 == nil }.isEmpty
               && latitude != invalid && longitude != invalid
               && accuracy != Int(invalid) /* && however you compare dates */
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't decode JSON strings into numeric values. The question strongly suggests the JSON is in the form `{"latitude": "123.456"}`, which is wrong, but a common way for JSON to be encoded. This also spreads Optionals to every user of `MyGPSCoords`, which is a very bad design. The structure should be validated one time, and then there should be no optionals (as in the original code).

Comment: i like the way you implement the isValid function.